# How to adjust result to equal mode values in R

Tags: r

The code below is generating the mode value considering the columns `Method1`, `Method2`, `Method3` and `Method4`. However, notice that for alternative `10` and `12` it has the same mode value, that is, it has a value of `2`. However, I would like my `Mode` column to have different values, as if it were a rank. Therefore, the alternative that had `Mode=1` is the best, but I have no way of knowing the second best alternative, because it has two numbers `2` in the `Mode` column. Do you have suggestions on what approach I can take?

```
database<-structure(list(Alternatives = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
    Method1 = c(1L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L), Method2 = c(1L, 
    8L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), Method3 = c(1L, 
    10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), Method4 = c(1L, 
    9L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
10L))

 ModeFunc <- function(Vec) {
    tmp <- sort(table(Vec),decreasing = TRUE)
    Nms <- names(tmp)
    if(max(tmp) > 1) {
      as.numeric(Nms[1])
    } else NA}
  
  
output <- database |> rowwise() |> 
mutate(Mode = ModeFunc(c_across(Method1:Method4))) %>% 
data.frame()

> output
   Alternatives Method1 Method2 Method3 Method4 Mode
1             3       1       1       1       1    1
2             4      10       8      10       9   10
3             5       7       6       7       6    6
4             6       8       7       8       7    7
5             7       9      10       9      10    9
6             8       6       9       6       8    6
7             9       5       4       4       5    4
8            10       3       2       2       3    2
9            11       4       3       3       4    3
10           12       2       5       5       2    2
```

**CHECK**

```
   output$Rank <- (nrow(output) + 1) - rank(-output$Mode, ties.method = "last")
   output|> 
   arrange(Mode)

   Alternatives Method1 Method2 Method3 Method4 Mode Rank
1             3       1       1       1       1    1    1
2            10       3       2       2       3    2    2
3            12       2       5       5       2    2    3
4            11       4       3       3       4    3    4
5             9       5       4       4       5    4    5
6             5       7       6       7       6    6    6
7             8       6       9       6       8    6    7
8             6       8       7       8       7    7    8
9             7       9      10       9      10    9    9
10            4      10       8      10       9   10   10
```

Comment: No. Your ranking produces ties. You haven’t defined how to break a tie. We might suggest ways of doing so, but we can’t know which way is most useful without context. You could, for example, use the second most frequent value to break a tie. Or the smallest value lower than the mode, or the smallest value greater than the mode. Or any other option you like. You know your data. You’re best placed to know what’s most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Limey! You're right, without context, it's hard to say something. I think that when you have the same `mode`, choose the `alternative` that has the lowest value. That is, in the case of `alternative` 10 and 12 it has the same mode value, that is, it has a value of 2, choose `alternative` 10, as the second in the ranking, you know? How could I do something like this in the code?

Answer (score 1):

OK.  Based on OP's comment above, Here's a solution that picks the row with the lowest value of `Alternatives` in case of ties.  You can generalise to any other tie break with an appropriate modification of the second `mutate`.

```
output |> 
  arrange(Mode) |>       # Sort by mode
  group_by(Mode) |>      # Assign intial ranks
  mutate(Rank=cur_group_id()) |> 
  arrange(Rank, Alternatives) |> # Sort and assign tie break
  mutate(TieBreak=row_number()) |> 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 10 × 8
   Alternatives Method1 Method2 Method3 Method4  Mode  Rank TieBreak
          <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <dbl> <int>    <int>
 1            3       1       1       1       1     1     1        1
 2           10       3       2       2       3     2     2        1
 3           12       2       5       5       2     2     2        2
 4           11       4       3       3       4     3     3        1
 5            9       5       4       4       5     4     4        1
 6            5       7       6       7       6     6     5        1
 7            8       6       9       6       8     6     5        2
 8            6       8       7       8       7     7     6        1
 9            7       9      10       9      10     9     7        1
10            4      10       8      10       9    10     8        1
```

Note that `cur_group_id()` required dplyr v1.0.0 or later and that `row_number()` takes account of groups when a data frame is grouped.

Comment: Thanks @Limey! Just one question, your reply is similar using `rank` function that I inserted in the question now? I saw that `ties.method = last` generates rank with different values.